# Print statement not executing within ipairs loop

Tags: lua

I have the following table defined which consists of tables defined under a string index as such:

```lua
local myTable = {
    ["str-1"] = {
        id = 1,
        value = "val"
    },

    ["str-2"] = {
        id = 2,
        value = "val",
    },

    ["str-3"] = {
        id = 3,
        value = "val",
    }
}

for i, table in ipairs(myTable) do
    print(i)
    print(table)
end
```

I'm attempting to loop through the contents of the table however the `print()` statements are not giving an output? I have placed a print statement to print both the current index of the loop and the table at that position.

Comment: please refer to the manual. you cannot use functions properly based on a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are attempting to use an `ipairs()` loop over an associative array.

Instead, you can use a `pairs()` loop which supports iteration where the index of a table is associative:

```lua
for i, table in pairs(myTable) do
    print(i)
    print(table)
end
```

A `pairs()` loop uses a key-value pair and works with associative tables, this also results in iteration not being conducted in order whereas an `ipairs()` uses an index-value pair, the likes of which can be used on a regular table defined with numerical indexes.

Comment: all Lua tables are associative arrays!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Lua Reference Manual: ipairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-ipairs)

> #### ipairs (t)
>
> Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t, and 0) so
> that the construction
>
> ```
>  for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> **will iterate over the key–value pairs (1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ..., up to
> the first absent index**.

As you see ipairs only works for sequences.

Your table does not have any key value pairs (1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ... so the generic for loop is terminated immediately.

Use [pairs](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-pairs)

> If t has a metamethod __pairs, calls it with t as argument and
> returns the first three results from the call.
>
> Otherwise, returns three values: the next function, the table t, and
> nil, so that the construction
>
> ```
>  for k,v in pairs(t) do body end
> ```
>
> **will iterate over all key–value pairs of table t**.
>
> See function next for the caveats of modifying the table during its
> traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Time to present a version that can do both...

```
tprint=function(self,...)
local args={...}
local start=args[1]
local stop=args[2]
if type(args[1])=='number' and type(args[2])=='number' then
 for i=start,stop do
  io.write(string.format('%d = %s\n',i,table.concat(self,'',i,i)))
 end
else
 for key,value in pairs(self) do
  io.write(string.format('%s = %s\n',key,value))
 end
end
end
```

With one table argument it is using `pairs()`
With table and two numbers it prints out start (first number) and stop (second number).
Example for `arg` that often starts with key `0`

```
-- Print out only key 0
> tprint(arg,0,0)
0 = /root/lua-5.4.0/src/lua
-- Using pairs()
> tprint(arg)
1 = -i
2 = -e
3 = setmetatable(arg,{__index={code={},concat=table.concat}}); 
0 = /root/lua-5.4.0/src/lua
```

I am using this as a metamethod for `arg` as `__call` or/and `__index.tprint`.